# Python numpy - iterating over an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This is an exercise from DataQuest.

I guess I'm trying to iterate over an array but it won't let me. How is an array different from a list?

32561 is the sample size, and 16280.50 is 50% male and 50% female.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

chi_squared_values = []

for i in range(1000):
    random_n = np.random.random((32561,))
    for array in random_n:
        male_count = 0
        female_count = 0
        for n in array: # Error on this line
            if n < 0.5:
                male_count =+ 1
            else:
                female_count =+ 1
        male_diff = (male_count - 16280.5) ** 2 / 16280.5
        female_diff = (female_count - 16280.5) ** 2 / 16280.5
        chi_squared_value = male_diff + female_diff
        chi_squared_values.append(chi_squared_value)

plt.hist(chi_squared_values)
plt.show()

# Output: TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

The correct answer for reference is:

```
chi_squared_values = []
from numpy.random import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in range(1000):
    sequence = random((32561,))
    sequence[sequence < .5] = 0
    sequence[sequence >= .5] = 1
    male_count = len(sequence[sequence == 0])
    female_count = len(sequence[sequence == 1])
    male_diff = (male_count - 16280.5) ** 2 / 16280.5
    female_diff = (female_count - 16280.5) ** 2 / 16280.5
    chi_squared = male_diff + female_diff
    chi_squared_values.append(chi_squared)

plt.hist(chi_squared_values)
```

Comment: That's not an array. That's a single number! Why do you think iterating over `random_n` would give you arrays?

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the quantities so you can see what's happening:

```
for i in range(1):
    random_n = np.random.random((5,))
    for array in random_n:
        print("array", array)
```

Output:

```
array 0.134163286857
array 0.872361053661
array 0.794873889688
array 0.68134812363
array 0.726452821311
```

`random_n` is simply an array of floats.  Thus, what you've named `array` is a single float.  You cannot iterate over that.

What are trying to achieve by changing the structure of the solution?  What is your inner loop supposed to do?

Comment: Okay. for some reason, I thought that range(1000) gave me 1000 extra arrays in the 32561 array. I removed the second for statement and remove one indent in the if statement. The code is taking a long time to run. Does appending many values to a list slow down the program or do I have some infinite loop?

Comment: If you thought that, then you need to back up a little and review what the `for` statement does.  All you get is to repeat the loop body 1000 times.

Comment: I don't know for sure what your slowdown is.  First, this is a separate problem; we need to you properly retire this one (for instance, accept an answer) and post your new problem as exactly that, with the code you're using.  If I make the changes you describe *ver batim*, the program fails for an undefined symbol.